# TweetQuote - hebrew not working

Tags: jquery

im trying to use tweetquote plugin for jquery,

when i use the default username: pauljcampbell its working perfectly,

when im changing to mine, raalcoil, it isnt..

ive worked it out a bit and found out its a lang problem, the default filter is for english, when im changing to lang:he , its not working.

```
<script src="{$base_url}tweet.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//<![CDATA[
tweetquote.load( {
    "username" : "raalcomm",
    "refreshrate" : 2000,
    "defaulttext" : "loading"
} );
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I have updated my post below !

Comment: If your problem is over, could you award me the bounty ?

Comment: srry i was sure i gave you, enjoy it , tnx very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I figured out the problem. The plug-in is not working because the tweets of the username that you are using doesn't appear in Twitter's search results in the first place . Try the following to check for your self:

1. open http://search.twitter.com
2. enter from:USERNAME  , replace USERNAME with your own.
3. if anything appears on this page , then it will most definitely appear using the TweetQuote plug-in.

**Original Post**
Open tweet.js ..

modify this line of code ( line# 93 ) :
        var api = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=1&callback=tweetquote.onApiCallback&lang=' + config.lang + "&";

into

```
    var api = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=1&callback=tweetquote.onApiCallback&';
```